# How to find files stored in SD card and downloaded files in Windows Phone 8.1 (Nokia Lumia 720)?

Tags: 8.1

I'm a new Nokia Lumia 720 user and the Windows 8 OS has made things very complicated :/

After inserting my old memory card into my phone, I'm unable to view my old voicenotes which I received through Whatsapp, and some videos too. Also, whenever I download a video, it says that the video has been saved to the Downloads folder but I have no clue where this so called "Downloads" folder is.

Yes, I can view these files when I connect my Phone to my laptop.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You should see your videos files throught "Video" app. Your audio files should be acessible throught "Music" app. Assuming that you are running the latest version of the OS, you can use the [files app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e) to browse directly to the file. Or you can try [MoliPlayer](http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/moliplayer-pro/19ea6d3e-e3d9-401d-b30a-f6471811fe08) to see all your videos and audio files in one single place.